# Coin tossed 6 times, twice. Probability of getting exact same sequence twice

Tags: probability

Apologies in case this question has been asked before, and answered as well. I have search through the forum, but couldn't find this exact solution. If it does exist, kindly point me towards the right direction.

My question is, what is the probability of tossing a coin 6 times, twice. (Each time has 6 tosses) and getting the same exact sequence of either heads or tails or both. E.g HTHHTH for the first cycle of tosses, then HTHHTH for the second cycle of tosses, in a row. or HHHHHH for the first cycle and HHHHHH for the immediate subsequent cycle.

Answer (score 5):

No matter what the first sequence is, the second one has to exactly match it, but there are no conditions on the first one. So the choice of the second is fixed, giving us only 1 favorable sequence out of the possible $2^6$. The probability is $2^{-6}$.